# how can I bind an OSX key binding locally in org-mode?

Tags: macos, emacs, org-mode

How can I bind an OSX key binding locally in org-mode (but not globally in Emacs)?

I added this to my .emacs but it didn't work:

```
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
         (lambda ()
          (local-set-key osx-key-mode-map (kbd "A-L") 'org-insert-link)
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

By default org-insert-link is bound to "C-c C-l", if you want to add another key binding for that locally you're code is close, but I think there are two minor issues:

1. It looks like you have an extra parameter 'osx-key-mode-map' in your call to local-set-key.
2. A key combo of the Alt / Meta key plus Shift plus l would be represented as "M-L".  If you want Apple / Command plus Shift plus l that would be "s-L".

So the code should look like:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "s-L") 'org-insert-link)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the org-mode specific key-map with the Command key, `(kbd "A-l")`, as in:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "A-l") 'org-insert-link)))
```